# Access images in appDataFolder for Google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to display some images in the browser within my google drive web app that I have previously uploaded into appDataFolder using the same app but not having success. I have gone thru the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata but unable to find any clue.

I have no problem doing the same when the images are stored outside of the appDataFolder. Any clue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") should include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It was due to poor documentation at google.

The documentation is at:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads